# Rewriting the Floor function in terms of the Heaviside Step Function and/or Sign Function

Tags: functions, approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

Is there a way to rewrite $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in terms of the Heaviside Step Function and/or Sign Function, or approximating it using them?

Comment: You can define it as an infinite sum of step functions, at least if the domain is a half-line rather than the whole line. I assume that $\lfloor -1.2 \rfloor = -2$ for you?

Comment: @I guess you're right: the domain I'm interested in is half-infinite-- only positive real numbers.

Comment: I guess in the general case you can write it as a difference of two infinite sums, one counting the integers in $(0,x]$ and the other counting the integers in $(0,-x]$ where by convention an interval with the endpoints in the wrong order is empty.

Comment: @Ian Is there a way to approximate it then?